# Hold session for select option value dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

Hi I have a select option when login but my select value can't hold a session. There's any wrong in my code ? Please check reference code below.

My form.php
I set a option value not working for session but my username can hold a session

```
<form name=frmTest id="form" class="form-signin" action="check.php" method="post">
    <div class="append-icon">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="user" class="form-control form-white username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="append-icon m-b-20">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" class="form-control form-white password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <i class="icon-lock"></i>
        <center>
          <select name=branch class="form-control form-white username" id="branch">
          <option selected> Select Branch </option>
          <option value='North'> North </option>
          <option value='South'> South </option>
          <option value='East'>  East </option>

        </select>
      </center>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block ladda-button" data-style="expand-left">Sign In</button>
    <p>


</form>
```

My check.php
I insert post both username and branch so i can get session for both but i can only get session from username

```
<?php

include 'functions.php';
include 'database/connect.php';

session_start();

$user   =   $_POST['username'];
$branch =   $_POST['branch'];

$rem = false;

if($load = $con->prepare("select * from login where username = ?")){
    $load->bind_param("s", $user);
    $load->execute();
    $load->store_result();
    $number = $load->num_rows;
    $load->close();
}

if($number === 0){
    echo 'Login failed';
    exit();
}else{
    if($active = $con->prepare("select active from login where username = ?")){
        $active->bind_param("s", $user);
        $active->execute();
        $active->bind_result($res);
        $active->fetch();
    }

    if($res === 0){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        echo 'Success';
    }else{
        echo 'User not activated';
    }
}
?>
```

My header.php and I include this on my header.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../login/functions.php';
include '../login/database/connect.php';
protect();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    echo $_SESSION['user'];

else if(isset($_COOKIE['user']))
    echo $_COOKIE['user'];

$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$branch = $_SESSION['branch'];
?>
```

Comment: I dont see anywhere where you actually store the branch into the session array?

Comment: You speak the truth squire @RiggsFolly

Comment: @Fred-ii- I do try my best to.... _Unless it would drop me in the ca ca_

Comment: See you at the loo @RiggsFolly I will leave a fresh roll for ya.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I dont care what the others say, yer a real gent squire

Comment: You are not storing $_SESSION['branch'] = $_POST['branch'] in your code.